# How to Disable Datepicker Calendar once the Date has been Set in Yii2 and Jquery?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, yii2

Here i like to explain my problem clearly,

This is my code

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'doa')->widget(
              DatePicker::className(), [
              'inline' => false,
              'clientOptions' => [
              'autoclose' => true,
              'format' => 'yyyy-m-dd',
              'todayHighlight' => true
            ]
        ]); ?>
```

Here once i set the date using datepicker, i need to disable the datepicker or make datepicker as Readonly.

if i try this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'doa')->widget(
                  DatePicker::className(), [
                  'inline' => false,
                  'readonly' => !empty($model->doa),
                  'clientOptions' => [
                  'autoclose' => true,
                  'format' => 'yyyy-m-dd',
                  'todayHighlight' => true
                ]
            ]); ?>
```

am getting error as : `Setting unknown property: dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker::readonly`

Answer (score 3):

Diable Client Event as:-

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'doa')->widget(
    DatePicker::className(), 
    [
        'inline' => false,
        'clientOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-m-dd',
            'todayHighlight' => true,
        ],
        'clientEvents' => [
            'changeDate' => false
        ],
        'options' => [
            'readonly' => 'readonly'
        ]
    ]
); ?>
```

Comment: field get disable, but if i click on the field, it showing me a datepicker

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'doa')->widget(
              DatePicker::className(), [
              'inline' => false,
              'disabled' => !empty($model->doa),
              'clientOptions' => [
              'autoclose' => true,
              'format' => 'yyyy-m-dd',
              'todayHighlight' => true
            ]
        ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just setting disabled didn't work for me, so here is my solution:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'doa')->widget(
          DatePicker::className(), [
          'inline' => false,
          'addon' => false,//To disable addon button with its events
          'disabled' => !empty($model->doa),
          'clientOptions' => [
             'autoclose' => true,
             'format' => 'yyyy-m-dd',
             'todayHighlight' => true
          ]
    ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For 'options' you have to use 'disabled' => 'disabled'

```
echo DatePicker::widget([
        'name' => 'termin',
        'id' => 'termin',
        'language' => 'cs',
        'template' => '{addon}{input}',
            'options' => [
                'autocomplete'=>'off',
                'disabled' => 'disabled'
            ],
            'clientOptions' => [
                'autoclose' => true,
                'format' => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
                'todayHighlight' => true,
            ]
    ]);
```